# Setting profiler for a multi process program in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, profiling

I have a profiler that records function entries in a python program as follows:

```
def tracefunc(frame, event, arg, indent=[0]):
      if event == "call":
          indent[0] += 2
          print("-" * indent[0] + "> call function", frame.f_code.co_name)
      elif event == "return":
          print("<" + "-" * indent[0], "exit function", frame.f_code.co_name)
          indent[0] -= 2
      return tracefunc
```

Inside my code I use it as:

```
import sys
import tracer

sys.setprofile(tracer.tracefunc)
```

this works fine for a single process program. But it doesn't log child processes when I'm using torch multiprocessing:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
p = mp.Process(target=run_parameter_server, args=(0, world_size))
p.start()
processes.append(p)
```

How can I set the profiler for those processes too?

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the example, and it works fine. Could you please paste the complete minimal reproducible example? Perhaps, the problem is in another part.